# From a web appn, how to run an exe on client machine without user interaction

Tags: java, javascript, java-web-start

I am developing a web application using HTML5, AngularJS, REST Webservices, Java etc. I will be hosting it over company's intranet. I have a peculiar requirement where I need to run exes which are already copied to client machine. The 'run' should be triggered from backend java code and user need not click on any UI link.

I am exploring Java Web Start, but I guess some user interaction in mandatory in it. If some signed content, certificates are required I can do that.

Is this feasible?

Comment: Please reorganize your question. Your web application seems irrelevant to your actual question. I'm assuming that you just need to find a way to execute *.exe files on remote machines.

Comment: Possibly a more successful line of inquiry might be to attack this from the perspective of running an executable on a remote machine through the local network rather than from the perspective of the web where I hope there is not a single way to make this happen. The web server itself is hosted on the intranet you say, which means you can treat it as a machine on the local network. There may be OS specific ways then to do what you need.

Comment: Gimby, I will explore this aspect as well. Thanks.

Comment: *"Is it feasible?"*  Hopefully not, since it would be a great way to deliver viruses and malware.

Comment: I am trying to explore **psexec** utility for the same. Able to execute exes on remote m/c using the same thru standalone java code. Now trying to do so thru java code deployed on tomcat.

Comment: I have resolved this issue by using sockets. Though its a very fragile solution, thats the best I could do. I have an utility running on client machine which polls certain ports and perform actions as per commands received on port. Sockets exists at server as well as client side. Each user is assigned particular port number. As this application runs in a LAN, as long as server ports are open and firewall is managed, it works fine.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is exactly what any virus builder dreams of. Therefor, it has been made VERY difficult. There are only 2 ways in which I think you could do this:

1. Use a java applet. It needs to be signed perfectly and the security settings in the users browsers need to be lowered. Even then I'm not entirely sure they don't have to click 'accept' somewhere.
2. Create a browser plugin. You could write a browser plugin, which would allow you to do basically anything you want. You would need to install it everywhere though.

If there is any way of getting around the requirement of running an exe from a web browser, I suggest you take it.

Comment: Running exes without user intervention is important for me. Believe me I am trying hard to avoid this assignment.

Comment: David, Can I control browser plugin from backend code so as to run exe?

Comment: Someway, somehow, I think so, yes. Unfortunately, I don't have any experience writing browser plugins. So even if it is possible, I couldn't tell you how.

Comment: Keep in mind that this suggestion does not mean that you build "a" plugin - you need to build X plugins, where X is the number of browsers that you want to support.

Comment: *"Even then I'm not entirely sure they don't have to click 'accept' somewhere."*  Of course the user has to approve the code!  Even then the browser might itself insert some 'are you sure?' prompts before it even considers launching a Java applet.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Like I said in my answer, if you lower the browser security settings this can sometimes be avoided. You would also make sure the browser/os trusts your certificate.